# Scipy - Error while using spherical Bessel functions

Tags: python, scipy, bessel-functions

I'm trying to draw plots in Python with Scipy module. According to http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/special.html I wrote code with `scipy.special.spherical_jn(n,x,0)`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.special as sp

from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})

def odrazTE(a,o,d):
    temp1 = sp.spherical_jn[1,a,0]
    temp2 = 1
    return abs(temp1/temp2)**2

t = np.arange(0.001, 2, 0.001)
plt.plot(t,odrazTE(t,t,1),label='TE1')
plt.show()
```

While I'm compiling the program, all I get is this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "standing-sphere.py", line 33, in <module>
    plt.plot(t,odrazTE(t,t,1),label='TE1')
  File "standing-sphere.py", line 15, in odrazTE
    temp1 = sp.spherical_jn[1,a,0]
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'spherical_jn'
```

There is way how to do it with regular Bessel function and relationship between Bessel and spherical Bessel function, but I don't like this solution because of derivative of sph.bess. function that I need too.

Is there any chance I have set something wrongly and it can be fixed to scipy.special.spherical_jn work?

Comment: What are those square brackets doing after `spherical_jn`?

Comment: My fault, but nothing changes with parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`scipy.special.spherical_jn`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.spherical_jn.html) was added in scipy version 0.18.0, which was released on July 25, 2016.  My guess is you are using an older version of scipy.  To check, run

```
import scipy
print(scipy.__version__)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have 0.13.3, upgrade of scipy solves my problem then. :)